# WorkManager with network contraints not running on android 9 emulator

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-9.0-pie

WorkManager enqueued a network restricted work, only enqueued without running on android 9 emulator

```
8532-8549 D/WM-PackageManagerHelper: androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.RescheduleReceiver enabled
8532-8549 D/WM-SystemJobScheduler: Scheduling work ID cdded304-5021-4e94-a13c-2e0746d54a58 Job ID 0
8532-8549 D/WM-GreedyScheduler: Starting tracking for [cdded304-5021-4e94-a13c-2e0746d54a58]
8532-8549 D/WM-ConstraintTracker: NetworkStateTracker: initial state = [ Connected=true Validated=false Metered=false NotRoaming=true ]
8532-8549 D/WM-NetworkStateTracker: Registering network callback
8532-8549 D/WM-GreedyScheduler: Constraints not met: Cancelling work ID cdded304-5021-4e94-a13c-2e0746d54a58
8532-8549 D/WM-PackageManagerHelper: androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.RescheduleReceiver enabled
8532-8549 D/WM-SystemJobScheduler: Scheduling work ID fde1a327-10dc-4356-8145-b1f624f99d48 Job ID 1
8532-8549 D/WM-GreedyScheduler: Starting tracking for [fde1a327-10dc-4356-8145-b1f624f99d48]
8532-8549 D/WM-GreedyScheduler: Constraints not met: Cancelling work ID cdded304-5021-4e94-a13c-2e0746d54a58
8532-8549 D/WM-GreedyScheduler: Constraints not met: Cancelling work ID fde1a327-10dc-4356-8145-b1f624f99d48
```

**EDIT**

```
fun enqueueUniqueWork() {
    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniqueWork(
        App.ANONYMOUS_LOGIN,
        ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP,
        OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<AnonymousLoginWork>()
            .setConstraints(
                Constraints.Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                    .build()
            )
            .build()
    )
}
```

**UPDATE**

I found that ConnectivityManager.activeNetwork doesn't has NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED capability when app running on android pie emulator, so the network constraint not met.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work/impl/constraints/controllers/NetworkConnectedController.java#49
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work/impl/constraints/trackers/NetworkStateTracker.java#118
From the source code, we can see the network constraint changed to **isConnected** && **isValidated**, which means, current active network must has 
NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED capability.

The question is: **How to config this on emulator?**

Comment: Have you tried to see if the same Work runs if you don't set the constraints in the WorkRequest?

Comment: Please provide the code that's causing this issue.  Where are you enqueuing your work?  All we can see from the logs are that some constraints aren't met, most likely your network constraints.

Comment: @pfmaggi the work will run if I remove the network constraints

Comment: @SumirKodes the work enqueued at Application.onCreate(), with only network constraint

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The tool that helped me figure out the issue was Android Studio Logcat - the `WorkManager` puts out traces for why the work failed to enqueue or start and this was very useful in my case.

In my case, it turned out that I had accidentally removed the `public` access modifier from my worker class constructor, so the `WorkManager` was not able to instantiate it. Once I made the constructor (and of course the class itself) `public`, the worker was successfully enqueued and ran.

Answer (score 0):

I am still having this problem in 2023. The only solution that I found was to tell work manager to ignore constraints in my test following the instructions at [Integration tests with WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/testing/persistent/integration-testing).

For example:

```kotlin
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
internal class TestWorkRequiringNetworkConnectionOnEmulator {

  val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext

  @Before
  fun setup() {
    val config =
        Configuration.Builder()
            .setMinimumLoggingLevel(Log.DEBUG)
            .setExecutor(SynchronousExecutor())
            .build()

    // Initialize WorkManager for instrumentation tests.
    WorkManagerTestInitHelper.initializeTestWorkManager(context, config)
  }

  suspend fun approveAllWorkManagerConditions(jobTag: String) {
      // Workaround problem in jobs with network contraints not running on emulator.
      val testDriver = WorkManagerTestInitHelper.getTestDriver(context)
      val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
      val jobs = workManager.getWorkInfosByTag(jobTag).await()
      for (j in jobs) {
        testDriver?.setAllConstraintsMet(j.id)
  }

  @Test
  fun myInstrumentedTest() = runBlocking {
    // run your test up until they get blocked
    approveAllWorkManagerConditions(JOB_TAG)
    // continue your test
  }

}
```